# Regex: match multiple times within regex defined region (emacs)

Tags: regex, emacs, syntax-highlighting

I'm working on syntax highlighting for a markdown + latex combination I use. The major-mode of the document is markdown, and the bit I'm stuck on is highlighting latex's special characters inside the latex blocks.

If we take the case of a latex environment:

```
\begin{align*}
    f(x) &= x^2
    g(x) &= x^3
\end{align*}
```

I can match the simple environment with (without emacs' escaping) `^\\begin{.*}(.|\n)*?\\end{.*}$`

(I am aware this doesn't work with environments within environments, I know one has to make the `{.*}` section the same for beginning and end - I'll happily take advice on the best way to do this too) EDIT: Fixed it, just have to capture the opening tag and then use it in the end tag.

I am interested in highlighting latex's special characters within the environment (but not outside it): these characters are `$#^_{}&`. If someone could point me in the direction of modifying my environment detector to have one or more groups containing these characters I'd be very grateful. (I'm not sure it's entirely possible).

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an *anchored* font-lock keyword, anchoring the matching at a point inside the environment. See the Elisp manual, node [Search-based Fontification](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Search_002dbased-Fontification.html#Search_002dbased-Fontification). See the descriptions of `(MATCHER . ANCHORED-HIGHLIGHTER)` and `(MATCHER HIGHLIGHTERS...)`.

(But be aware that regexps are not strong enough to do the kind of matching you want to do here, in general. I guess you already know this, based on your comment about nesting etc.)

Comment: Thanks, I did actually manage to get it working by roughly this method